# Apache Impala - YARN like CPU utilization report for queries (on Cloudera)

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cpu-usage, cloudera, impala

We have YARN and Impala co-located on the same cloudera cluster, YARN utilization report and YARN history server provides more valuable information like YARN CPU (Vcores) and Memory usage.

Does something like that exist for IMPALA where I can fetch CPU and memory usage per query and as a whole on the Cloudera cluster.

Precisely  I want to know how many Vcores are utilized out of its CPU allocation.

For example, an Impala Query takes 10s to execute a query, and lets say it used 4 vcores and 50MB of RAM, how do I find out that 4 vcores utilized.

Is there any direct way to query this from the cluster or any other method on how to compute the CPU utilization?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information through the Cloudera Manager Charts. You can find an overview of all available metrics [on their website](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_metrics.html) or by clicking on the help symbol on the right side when creating a new chart.

There are quite a few categories for Impala that might be worth a read for you. For example the [general Impala metrics](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_metrics_impala.html#cm_metrics_impala) and the [Impala query metrics](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_metrics_impala_query.html#cm_metrics_impala_query). The query metrics for example contain "memory_usage" measured in byte and the general metrics contain "impala_query_cm_cpu_milliseconds_rate" and "impala_query_memory_accrual_rate". These seem to be relevant for your usecase, but check them out and the linked sites to see which ones fit your usecase.

More information is available from the service page of the Impala service in your Cloudera Manager. You can find out more about this page [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cm_dg_impala_queries.html), but for example the linked page mentions:

> The Impala Queries page displays information about Impala queries that are running and have run in your cluster. You can filter the queries by time period and by specifying simple filtering expressions.

It also allows you to display "Threads: CPU Time" and "Work CPU Time" for each query, which again could be relevant for you.

That is all the information available from Impala.